# Execution of script.sql with MERGE (with INSERT and UPDATE) statement wont work via SQLPlus. But it works in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

This is my `script.sql` file with 1 `MERGE` row:

```
MERGE INTO MYTABLE t1 USING (SELECT '123456' RUT_SOCIEDAD, SYSDATE FEC_PROCESO FROM DUAL) t2 ON (t1.RUT_SOCIEDAD = t2.RUT_SOCIEDAD) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.FEC_PROCESO = t2.FEC_PROCESO WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (RUT_SOCIEDAD,FEC_PROCESO) VALUES (t2.RUT_SOCIEDAD,t2.FEC_PROCESO);
EXIT;
```

The line of `MERGE` works fine in `SQL Developer`, but I have about 100 thousand rows (one MERGE per row) that I need to put in the script file.
When I run the script execution line in CMD (`username/password@databasename @script.sql`) for SQLPlus, the execution freezes, without responding at all.

I've tried enclosing the code in a `BEGIN-END` block like this but it didn't work:

```
BEGIN
MERGE INTO MYTABLE t1 USING (SELECT '123456' RUT_SOCIEDAD, SYSDATE FEC_PROCESO FROM DUAL) t2 ON (t1.RUT_SOCIEDAD = t2.RUT_SOCIEDAD) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.FEC_PROCESO = t2.FEC_PROCESO WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (RUT_SOCIEDAD,FEC_PROCESO) VALUES (t2.RUT_SOCIEDAD,t2.FEC_PROCESO);
END;
/
END
EXIT;
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the commit operator ?

Comment: see full query for cmd...
such a request cannot be wrapped in an anonymous block

Comment: You have an extra `END` in your script.

Comment: Did you roll back the SQL Developer session before trying to run the same statement again through your script? If not it will be blocking... (And why do you need one merge per row - can't your `using` clause generate the data to merge them all at once?)

Comment: If you are processing a script with 100,000 statements why do you expect that it will respond? Surely the client (SQL\*Plus) will be busy processing the script and will respond when it has finished.

Comment: @alex poole you have reason, I had unconmmited changes. Thanks!!